# Angular 5 cli can't load Material style

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm developing a web app in Angular 5 using the Angular Material library for the interface.

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/common": "~5.2.6",
"@angular/compiler": "~5.2.6",
"@angular/core": "~5.2.6",
"@angular/forms": "~5.2.6",
"@angular/http": "~5.2.6",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~5.2.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.2.6",
```

I tried the different ways to add the css

1. add 
   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css">` to index.html file
2. Add the following

   ```
   "styles": [
     "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"    
   ]
   ```

to `.angular.cli.json`

3. Create a `styles.scss` file in the src folder, add these files

   ```
   @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
   @import '~https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
   ```

however this doesn't work at all, the console shows the message

```
that:core.es5.js:139 Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
```

Comment: What is not working? Can please specify the error type or desired output? What elements are you putting to check?

Comment: the theme is not working, app could not find Angular Material core theme.

Comment: did you follow all steps given here https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add style.scss file to your styles:[] array and remove `"../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",` from styles array as you are importing it in your scss file.

ie

```
"styles": [ 
"../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css", // remove this line
"styles.scss" //add this line 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In **src/styles.css**

**Put** `@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

Anyway a style.css file was supposed to be there in the src folder, what was the reason to create it manually?